# Query not displaying products from custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a custom post type and I'm unable to fetch the posts and display them. I used the following code for ordinary posts and that worked fine. What am I missing? I have also added the function in which relates to the custom post type.

```
<div class="slider-wrap">   
    <div class="card-slider">   
        <?php
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'reviews',
                'posts_per_page' => 12
            );
            $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
        ?>
        <?php if ($the_query->have_posts()): ?>
            <?php while ($the_query->have_posts()):
                $the_query->the_post(); ?>
                <div class="card">
                    <h3><?php the_field('review_title'); ?></h3>
                    <p><?php the_field('review_description'); ?></p>
                    <h6><?php the_field('customer_name'); ?></h6>
                </div>
            <?php
                endwhile;
                wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            <?php
            else: ?>
            <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
            <?php
            endif; 
        ?>      
    </div>
</div>
```

// Our custom post type function

```
function create_posttype() {
 
    register_post_type( 'reviews',
    // CPT Options
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Reviews' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Review' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'reviews'),
            'show_in_rest' => true,
 
        )
    );
}
// Hooking up our function to theme setup
add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype' );
```

Comment: did you create custom post by CPT plugin?

Comment: ACF I have sorted it now, There was a spelling mistake.

Comment: empty value is printing or showing error?